# Android: Stopping random image being used more than once at the same time

Tags: android, image, button, random

Hi im currently setting button images to have random backgrounds. I have 9 buttons and 9 images each button needs one of the images assigned to it. Currently im using the same random int so all the buttons look the same. How can I make it so images don't repeat so if image one is already on a button none of the other buttons can have it. The random feature is important as I don't want to have the images fixed to just the one button.

He's my random setup:

```
private void nextBUTImage() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int rndInt = rand.nextInt(9)+ 1 ; 
            String imgName = "b" + rndInt;
            int ids = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
            but1.setBackgroundResource(ids);
            but9.setBackgroundResource(ids);
            but4.setBackgroundResource(ids);

            but3.setBackgroundResource(ids);
            but5.setBackgroundResource(ids);
            but6.setBackgroundResource(ids);

            but2.setBackgroundResource(ids);
            but8.setBackgroundResource(ids);
            but7.setBackgroundResource(ids);
            }
```

What process can I use I did try an if statement but wasn't feasible I have been wondering about using states but not sure how to set that up. Help with this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array of the image identifiers.
Then randomize that array.
Then assign them out in order (but1 will be assigned array[0], but2 is array[1]..).